# php: writing to file using fputcsv messes up format

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a question using `fputcsv` for writing arrays to file in php.  My code:

```
$outfile = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
fputcsv($outfile, $text);
```

My `$text` array:

```
[0] => "http://elvisduran.com/beermj\n\n\n(This is so cool!)\n"
[1] => "VIDEO: Here's the hilarious video of Ryan Lewis :)"
[2] => "Listen to a new non-album track from Lily Allen"
[3] => "UH OH! Someone's gonna get fired... \n\nOH WELL LOOOOOOOOOOK! "
[4] => "spoken word video featuring Pamela Anderson"
[5] => "Alexander Shulgin, cientista considerado do MDMA relacionados \303\240 psicologia, morreu nesta segunda nos Estados Unidos.\n\n"
```

But my `output.txt` looks like:

```
http://elvisduran.com/beermj


(This is so cool!)
","VIDEO: Here's the hilarious video of Ryan Lewis :)","Listen to a new non-album track from Lily Allen","UH OH! Someone's gonna get fired...

OH WELL LOOOOOOOOOOK! ","spoken word video featuring Pamela Anderson","Alexander Shulgin, cientista considerado o pioneiro nos estudos do MDMA relacionados à psicologia, morreu nesta segunda nos Estados Unidos.
```

Anyone have any idea why `fputcsv` is messing up my line breaks and inserting random ","??

I would like my output to be one array value per line, but if there's a line break `\n` then put on new line like:

```
http://elvisduran.com/beermj
(This is so cool!)
VIDEO: Here's the hilarious video of Ryan Lewis :)
Listen to a new non-album track from Lily Allen
UH OH! Someone's gonna get fired...
OH WELL LOOOOOOOOOOK!
spoken word video featuring Pamela Anderson
Alexander Shulgin, cientista considerado do MDMA relacionados à psicologia, morreu nesta segunda nos Estados Unidos.
```

Comment: output looks like it matches to me you have "\n\n\n" so you get three line breaks

Comment: The output you're after simply isn't csv.... fputcsv() isn't messing anything up, but is giving you exactly the format that it's supposed to give (a csv format file)

Comment: probably just want a `foreach()` loop with some cleaning up to remove the extra line breaks. if you didn't need to clean the extra line breaks you could just use `implode()`